# Ubuntu 22.04 freezes randomly on my Lenovo Ideapad Gaming 3 laptop

Tags: 22.04, lenovo, freeze, ideapad

I have installed Ubuntu 22.04 on my Lenovo Ideapad Gaming 3 laptop. It freezes randomly anytime and often after boot. In that case I have to long press power button and shut down the system and then start it. I remember this happening with my previous Lenovo laptop with older ubuntu version also which I bought 7 years ago. Please help with a solution.